# mvc - reference script code from view inside js file

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, razor, model-view-controller, reference

If we want our js file will "know" names of functions and variables from another js file we can reference the other file like so:

```
/// <reference path="someOtherFile.js" />
```

But what if my "other" code is inside a script tag within a cshtml view?
how can i let my js file "know" the names of variables and function inside a view?

I can't do that of course:

```
/// <reference path="someView.cshtml" />
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: omg i just found out that i actually can reference a cshtml file. my problem was that i had a wrong relative path to it. this should work with a correct path to the file {/// <reference path="someView.cshtml" />}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question in  case someone else will come across the same situation.

After a little while i figure out that we can actually pass to the reference path a `cshtml` file, my mistake was that i had a wrong relative path to the view file.

so this should work just fine:

```
/// <reference path="someView.cshtml" />
```